# How do I make a webpage display what platform and browser its being viewed in?

Tags: language-agnostic

I need a webpage to display if its being viewed on a PC/Mac, iphone, etc and also what browser its being run on.  Anyone know how I would go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You typically get this information through the `User-agent:` HTTP header sent by your browser. If you were using PHP, you'd get this by reading `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`. PHP also has a higher level `[get_browser][1]` API to read this data.

If you're using another scripting language in your web app, you'll need to look up the equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use Javascript, and the easiest way to use Javascript is to use a library like jQuery.  jQuery has .browser detection flags that'll give you what you're looking for.

[jQuery.support](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/): browser-specific CAPABILITIES (preferred)

[jQuery.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/): browser identity (deprecated)

NOTES:

1. You can try to determine "browser type" on either the client (web browser) or the server (e.g. IIS or Apache; in .Net or PHP).
2. Simply reading "browser type" (e.g. from an http return variable) is quite often inaccurate.  A better strategy is to "probe" for browser type, using different heuristics.  jQuery simplifies this for you.
3. A better strategy still is to determine browser CAPABILITIES, rather than "browser type".  jQuery simplifies this, too.

'Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using server-side code if the page is dynamically generated. For example, if you're using PHP you can use the [get_browser()](http://php.net/get_browser) function. Other language should have similar capabilities, via the User-Agent header sent by the browser.

You can also do it client-side in Javascript. Some details on this process can be found here: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need!

http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/useragent

http://jasonlau.biz/userinfo/test1.html